# MS Access VBA Dynamically Show Pics From URL

Tags: vba, image, ms-access

I found this code from here:
[Show Pictures Directly From URLs in Access Forms and Reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

I have this code on my form:

```
Public Function PeopleImage()
'FUNCTION TO SET THE IMGPEOPLEPIC WITH THE CURRENT PERSON'S PHOTO, IF THE PHOTO CAN BE FOUND. OTHERWISE A STOCK IMAGE SAYING NO PIC FOUND WILL SHOW
    Dim PeoplePic As String
    Dim NoPeoplePic As String
    Dim ImgDwnld As String

    PeoplePic = "https://TheWebAddress.com/People%20Photos/" & Nz(Me.PersonID, 0) & ".jpg"
    ImgDwnld = "\\AppServer\AppDir\Storage\Images\" & Nz(Me.PersonID, 0) & ".jpg"
    DownloadFile PeoplePic, ImgDwnld, False
    NoPeoplePic = "\\AppServer\AppDir\Storage\NoPeoplePic.jpg"

    If FileExists(ImgDwnld) Then
        Me.ImgPeoplePic.Picture = ImgDwnld
    Else
        Me.ImgPeoplePic.Picture = NoPeoplePic
    End If

    Me.ImgPeoplePic.Requery

End Function
```

When I added the image control ImgPeoplePic I set it to the NoPeoplePic, so that a picture would be set.  Now, when I load the form and navigate, it looks like the photo is reloading (it blinks), but it just keeps showing the stock NoPeoplePic.

Anyone know what I'm missing? I feel like I'm so close. I just don't understand what it's not putting in the image that it downloads.  I verified that the image downloads to the directory, and that it is there.  I debug the path and image and it pulls up with no problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it work as expected with locally-saved images?

Comment: @ashleedawg: The files are downloaded, thus local.

Comment: is `Me.ImgPeoplePic.Picture = ImgDwnld` being hit when you debug your code?

Comment: You could bind the picture control as suggested in the article. Then all you need is to  include the function in your query: `Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;`.

Comment: Yes, when I hit the If FileExists(ImgDwnld) Then with a break point, the imgDnwnld has the path to the file, and yes, when I step into the code, Me.ImgPeoplePic.Picture = ImgDwnld gets hit.

Comment: Gustav, are you saying I need to save the path to a table?  That makes this way more complicated in that I really don't need to store that in a table. This is not my schema, so I'm doing what I can to not change things and just develop the interface.

Comment: I got it!  I was trying to get the .picture property to update, and it was. I also tried setting the control source. It's a property on the image, but you can't reference in VBA, but it is there, and it was set to = "\\path\etc\noimage.jpg" so with that not changing, the pic didn't change.  I cleared that out and now the picture changes perfectly!!!!

Comment: No, save the Url of the picture if you can't build it like you did. In your case just use`Me.ImgPeoplePic.Picture = UrlContent(0, PeoplePic)`.`UrlContent` handles the download without a local temp file if you ommit a path.

Comment: One note, in case this helps someone else, the line :
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" had to be updated to Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" 
If you are working with 64 bit office.